# Performing schema validation on incoming SOAP messages in WebSphere

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere

I've got some webservices and I'd like to do schema validation on the incoming messages. From my research, I've seen that there is an annotation `@SchemaValidation`, but it's only available on Oracle's JBoss (and possibly on WebLogic and Glassfish as well?) and not on WebSphere.

The only solution I could think of for WebSphere was to write a custom SOAP handler and validate incoming XML there, but the problem is I don't know how to pass the validation errors to my web service implementation class so I can return a fault that contains the errors to the client.

Are there any better ways to validate SOAP messages on WebSphere (version 7)?

Comment: [Be aware of a "bug" that send just a "Internal Error" message to the client][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805119/jax-ws-server-side-soaphandler-that-returns-fault-gets-internal-error-on-websp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha... I had to throw a `SOAPFaultException` from the custom `SOAPHandler`, like this:

```
try
{
    ...
    ...
    validator.validate(source); 
}
catch (SAXException saxe)
{
    System.out.println("SAXException occurred");
    SOAPFault fault = null;
    try
    {
        fault = SOAPFactory.newInstance().createFault();
        fault.setFaultString(saxe.getMessage());
    }
    catch (SOAPException soape)
    {
        LOG.error("Error creating SOAPFault: "+soape.getMessage());
    }
    throw new SOAPFaultException(fault);
}
```

The `SOAPFaultException` gets sent back the calling client and they can see the validation error that their message caused.